# Item Command Event of List View is not getting fire in composite Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following is my code for generating Composite List View.

```
this.itemValueListView = new ListView();
this.itemValueListView.ID = "ItemValueListViewId";
this.itemValueListView.ItemTemplate = new ItemTemplate();  
this.itemValueListView.ItemCommand += new EventHandler<ListViewCommandEventArgs>(this.itemValueListView_ItemCommand); //Here I am Creating the event
```

here is my event code.

```
protected void itemValueListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "EditData")
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i have created the ItemCommand Event but its not getting fire when i am clicking on button which is inside List View

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx there's not a command called "EditData", but there is one called "Edit", however.

Comment: i have given my button commandName="EditData" , then also it is not working.

Comment: does your page Get Post Back? if yes you should fill your listview once again on postBack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your page Get Post Back? if yes you should fill your listview once again on postBack

Comment: yes my page is getting post back . and list view is also getting fill.

Comment: thank you its done . now I am binding my list view again on page load ,so its working now.

Comment: Will you please tell me how to edit data which is inside Generic List<string>